# How do you check for a type in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to tell the program to search an array(that’s meant to be only numbers) if it contains any element that’s a string.

Also, the array is made up of the arguments to a function. Can someone please help? I’ve been trying to figure this out for at least an hour! This is what i did so far:

```js
const sumAll = function(…args){
  const newArray = Array.from(args)
  for(let i = 0; i < newArray.length; i++){
    if(newArray[i] === NaN){
    return “ERROR”
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for the function [`isNaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN)

```js
const sumAll = function(...args){
  const newArray = Array.from(args)
  for(let i = 0; i < newArray.length; i++){
    if(isNaN(newArray[i])){
      return "ERROR"
    }
  }
}

console.log(sumAll(1,2,3)) // no output - undefined

console.log(sumAll(1,"two",3)) // error
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let foundString = arrayWithPossiblyString.find(i=>isNaN(5-i));
```

Explanation:

1. 5-"a" is a NaN.
2. isNaN function can be used to chec if something is NaN

Answer (score 0):

You can use `arguments` keyword to access all the variables which would be passed as arguments to that specific function. Further you can use isNaN function to determine weather the given argument is a number or not.

```
function check(){
    const arr = arguments
    for(const item of arr) {
        if(isNaN(item)){
            return "Error"
        }
    }
}

check(1, "Hello", "4")
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using the `isNaN` function:

```
...
if(isNaN(newArray[i])) {
   return "ERROR";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could check with [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) and take [`isNaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) as callback.

```js
const sumAll = function(...args) {
    if (args.some(isNaN)) return "ERROR";
}

console.log(sumAll(1, 2, 3));     // undefined
console.log(sumAll(1, "two", 3)); // ERROR
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const sampleErrorArr = ['zero', 1, 2, 3, 4,]
const sampleArr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

function sumAll(arr) {
    let sum = 0
    let hasNumber = true
    arr.forEach((item, index) => {
        if (typeof item === 'number') {
            let temp = sum + item
            sum = temp
        }
        else {
            hasNumber = false
        }
    })

    return hasNumber == true ? sum : "Error"
}

console.log(sumAll(sampleErrorArr)) //Error
console.log(sumAll(sampleArr)) // 15
```